# Is there anything wrong with using requires after output starts printing?

Tags: perl

Example:

```
my $page = $args{'p'};
exit 1 if $page =~ /[^\d\w]/;

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

print "<html><head></head><body>";

require "$page.pl";

somefunc();

print "</body></html>";
```

Is there anything wrong with using the require after the output has started or should all requires be at the top of the script?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, other than what is normally wrong with using `require "file";` to reuse code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

But if you want or need more consistency in your scripts, you could rewrite the code in the required script as a subroutine. For example:

```
##### old page.pl ######
print "This is the body.<P>\n";
1;

##### old cgi script #####
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head></head><body>\n";
require "page.pl";
```

---

```
##### new page.pl ######
sub page_body {
    print "This is the body.<P>\n";
}
1;

##### new cgi script #####
require "page.pl";                    # now at the top of script
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head></head><body>\n";
&page_body;
```

Comment: Indeed, one of the first steps in refactoring old monolithic cgi scripts (with inlined HTML, no functions etc) is to divide functionality into separate files and using `require`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no need for all `require`s to be at the top. Though, if the `require` fails, your HTML would be halfway sent already. :-P