# In Perl, is it better to use a module than to require a file?

Tags: perl

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178871/is-there-anything-wrong-with-using-requires-after-output-starts-printing) got me thinking about different methods of code reuse: `use` vs. `require` vs. `do`

I see a lot of posts here where the question centers around the use of `require` to load and execute code.  This seems to me to be an obvious bad practice, but I haven't found any good resources on the issue that I can point people to.

[perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-require-and-use?) covers the difference between `use` and `require`, but it doesn't offer any advice in regard to preference (as of 5.10--in [5.8.8 there is a quick bit of advice in favor of use](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlfaq8.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-require-and-use?)).

This topic seems to suffer from a lack of discussion.  I have a few questions I'd like to see discussed:

1. What is the preferred method of code reuse in Perl?

   - `use ModuleName;`
   - `require ModuleName;`
   - `require 'file.pl';`
   - `do 'file.pl';`
2. What is the difference between `require ModuleName` and `require "file.pl"`?
3. Is it ever a good idea to use `require "file.pl"`?  Why or why not?

Comment: Did you mean `require Module` or maybe `do "file"` instead of `require "file"`?

Comment: @Michael, `require "file"` actually uses `do "file"` to process its arugment, but it will only operate on a given file one time.

Comment: @daotoad: That's not what I was asking about. Typically `do` is used for *.pl files while `require` is used for *.pm files. The file extension doesn't matter, of course, but by convention *.pl hasn't meant "perl library" for a long time. I was trying to clarify if you were referring to the old usage or if the question should be modified to reflect the three ways of loading external code (`use`, `require`, and `do`). It would make more sense (to me) to include all three forms in the discussion.

Comment: @Michael, yes, I mean the old style usage.  For whatever reason, I see more people using `require` on SO than I see using `do`.  It does make sense to include the use of `do` in the question.  If you have a good idea on the wording, please edit the question.  The goal is to get a good resource to point people at, instead of rewriting the same response ("use modules instead") over and over.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Standard practice is to use `use` most of the time, `require` occasionally, and `do` rarely.

`do 'file'` will execute `file` as a Perl script. It's almost like calling `eval` on the contents of the file; if you `do` the same file multiple times (e.g. in a loop) it will be parsed and evaluated each time which is unlikely to be what you want. The difference between `do` and `eval` is that `do` can't see lexical variables in the enclosing scope, which makes it safer. `do` is occasionally useful for simple tasks like processing a configuration file that's written in the form of Perl code.

`require 'file'` is like `do 'file'` except that it will only parse any particular file one time and will raise an exception if something goes wrong. (e.g. the file can't be found, it contains a syntax error, etc.) The automatic error checking makes it a good replacement for `do 'file'` but it's still only suited for the same simple uses.

The `do 'file'` and `require 'file'` forms are carryovers from days long past when the *.pl file extension meant "Perl Library." The modern way of reusing code in Perl is to organize it into modules. Calling something a "module" instead of a "library" is just semantics, but the words mean distinctly different things in Perl culture. A library is just a collection of subroutines; a module provides a namespace, making it far more suitable for reuse.

`use Module` is the normal way of using code from a module. Note that `Module` is the package name as a bareword and not a quoted string containing a file name. Perl handles the translation from a package name to a file name for you. `use` statements happen at compile time and throw an exception if they fail. This means that if a module your code depends on isn't available or fails to load the error will be apparent immediately. Additionally, `use` automatically calls the `import()` method of the module if it has one which can save you a little typing.

`require Module` is like `use Module` except that it happens at runtime and does not automatically call the module's `import()` method. Normally you want to use `use` to fail early and predictably, but sometimes `require` is better. For example, `require` can be used to delay the loading of large modules which are only occasionally required or to make a module optional. (i.e. use the module if it's available but fall back on something else or reduce functionality if it isn't.)

Strictly speaking, the only difference between `require Module` and `require 'file'` is that the first form triggers the automatic translation from a package name like `Foo::Bar` to a file name like `Foo/Bar.pm` while the latter form expects a filename to start with. By convention, though, the first form is used for loading modules while the second form is used for loading libraries.

Answer (score 9):

There is a major preference for using `use`, because it happens at an earlier state `BEGIN {}` during compilation, and the errors tend to be propagated to the user at a more appropriate time. It also calls the `sub import {}` function which gives the caller control over the import process. This is something that is heavily used. You can get the same effect, by calling the specific namespace's `import`, but that requires you to know the name of the namespace, and the file, and to code the call to the subroutine... which is a lot more work. Conversely, `use`, just requires you to know the namespace, and then it requires the file with the matching namespace -- thus making the link between namespaces and files less of an conscious to the user.

Read [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), and [`perldoc -f require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), for more information. Per [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):
`use` is the same as `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }` Which is just a lot more ugly.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is around import/export. `use` is preferred when you're making use of a module because it allows you to specify which routines you wish to import into your namespace :

```
use MyModule qw(foo bar baz); # allows foo(), bar() and baz() to be used

use MyModule qw(); # Requires explicit naming (e.g. MyModule::foo).
```

`use` also gives runs the module's `import()` procedure which is often used to set the module up.

See the perldoc for [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) for more detail.

Comment: Actually, they're one in the same. In your example `MyModule::import()` is accepting `qw(foo bar baz)` and doing the exportation itself. It is the same facility, `Exporter`, and `Sub::Exporter` just generate an `import()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `use` to module will include module during compile time which increases speed but uses more memory, whereas using `require` module will include during run time. Requiring a module without using import when needed uses less memory but reduces speed.