# How do I use Perl's import, use, require and do?

Tags: perl, import

Can someone explain exactly the usage recomandations regarding the 4 perl imports: `do`, `import`, `use` and `require`?

I'm looking for practical recommendations and keeping in mind possible issues that might arise in the context of [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) or something similar.

We all love **simple examples**, good ones!

So far the best resource I found was `http://soniahamilton.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/perl-use-require-import-and-do/` , but this missed to consider the implications of [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/).

Comment: How is *Quick notes for me; not meant to be authoritative* "the best resource" you found?

Comment: We have an entire chapter on this in _Intermediate Perl_. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180554/in-perl-is-it-better-to-use-a-module-than-to-require-a-file

This is a better post


Please refer it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should first read [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) and [`perldoc -f require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

They are excellent resources and explain how `use` works, how it invokes `import` and then `require`, and how you could theoretically implement `require` in terms of `do`.

If you have already read them, do you still have any **specific** open questions that the standard documentation doesn't cover well enough and you would like to have answered in more detail?

Answer (score 13):

`do` will call the code, no ifs, ands, or buts, at runtime. This is usually a bad idea, because if that's happening, you should really probably be putting it into a subroutine.

`require` will call exactly once and then no more, at runtime. it can do it for a package, too, in which case it will actually go find that package for you.

`use` does everything require does in the package case, then calls `import` in that package.

`import` is a function defined in a package. it gets called by `use`, but it's not otherwise special.

Comment: You forgot to mention that `use` happens at **compile time**.  `use Foo;` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import(); }`

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the mod_perl documentation for [use(), require(), do()](http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#toc_use____require____do_____INC_and__INC_Explained)

Answer (score -2):

Since this question didn't gather more than RTFM as an 'answer':

Create a file called Example.pm in the same directory (or relative, like ./lib) and add these lines

```
package Example;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(subroutine1 subroutine2 etc)
1;
```

In your main script add these lines

```
use lib '.';
use Example qw(subroutine1 subroutine2 etc);
```

Subroutines named in both export_ok and use qw lists are available in the main script.

Bart...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Where's the part about `do`? Or `require`? or `import`?