# use of require in Perl

Tags: perl, require

I'm trying to use require multiple times in my code, but I can to run it once.

```
if ($value =~ "test") {
  require "mycode1.pm";  # Execute perfect
}

if ($value =~ "code") {
    require "mycode1.pm";  # Not execute
}

if ($value =~ "last") {
  require "mycode1.pm";    # # Not execute
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't run, could you please help me?

Comment: [`require`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require) is used to ensure that a module has been loaded, if it has already been loaded once it will not be loaded again. If you want to run the code in a file multiple times you can use [`do`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Perl, is it better to use a module than to require a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180554/in-perl-is-it-better-to-use-a-module-than-to-require-a-file)

Comment: @zb226 thanks very much for help. ;)

Comment: See [What is the difference between library files and modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379109/589924)

Comment: just make a sub and call it when needed. it's no specific for Perl only, a general practice, that's why sub's are made for.

Answer (score 1):

As you've been told in the comments, Perl keeps a record of which libraries have already been loaded, so `require` will only be called once for each file.

A couple of notes on your code.

The right-hand operand to the binding operator should be a match (`m/.../`), a substitution (`s/.../.../`) or a transliteration (`tr/.../.../`). You're using strings, which are silently converted to matches at runtime - but it's better to be more explicit.

```
$value =~ /test/
```

Given that the results of your three `if` tests are all the same, it's probably worth converting them into a single test.

```
if ($value =~ /test|code|last/) {
   ...
}
```